# cant write text file in c

Tags: c, file, text

Im trying to learn c, I'm using tutorialspoint, and the function they give me doesn't do anything on my computer, the function is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
    fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have write access to "/tmp"?

Comment: try write other folder. (It might be the work of back program  to remove the used files.)

Comment: Check the result of `fopen()`. If it can't create file, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: Please show your exact run log and how you are checking the results. Are you running this in Windows by any chance?

Comment: I am using windows, is there any problem with it?

Comment: It seems that there is no permission to write. try write other folder.

Comment: Do you already have a tmp folder in your current drive when running the program?

Comment: @ash There is nothing wrong with using Windows. However, `/tmp` is not a standard Windows directory whereas it is in Linux. That's why I'm asking you to show your exact run log and how you are checking the results (e.g. the exact commands you run to verify the result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to introduce some error checking with file streams

Do

```
fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+"); 
/* 
 * Try creating the file in the same folder for a start
 */

if(fp!=NULL)
{
fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
}
else
{

     /* There are multiple reasons you can't open a file like :
      * You  don't have permission to open it
      * A parent directory doesn't exist and so on.
      */

printf("Can't open the file for write\n");
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: still didn't change anything

Comment: @Ash : You may put the file in the program directory for a start. Change `/tmp/test.txt` to `test.txt`

Comment: well, the file is still empty

Comment: @Ash : So there is a file? Also there is a chance that you're looking the wrong file . Did you try changing `/tmp/test.txt` to `test.txt` in your code. After you run the code. You should be looking at the same folder where your code is

Comment: when I create one there is, if not, it doens't create it

Comment: @Ash : Did you change the code like I have given? Did you get any error opening the file? Please see the previous comment too..

Comment: it doens't give me any error code, I just dont know why this doesnt work

Comment: @Ash : It might sound silly , I have encountered such scenarios in the past where I looked at the wrong place for the file.. Also, you can clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @Ash : May I know what did you figure out?

Comment: I changed the directories to the GitHub one, and it works there, maybe it was just the permissions that didn't allow me to write on the file.

Comment: @Ash : Okie Dokie  :D

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new file test.txt in /tmp directory and writes two lines using two different functions. Try find test.txt inside /tmp folder.

Comment: I can't find it, I tried creating the folder and deleting it, with and without the file, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: The folder is `/tmp` by the way

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` won't create directories for you.
You need to create a tmp folder at the root of your current disk before running this program.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to create the `temp` directory from where you executing this code because **fopen** is not creating the directory so,than after you need to check following code:

> ```
>  #include <stdio.h>
>  int main ()
>  {
>    FILE *fp;
>    fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");
>     if(fp == NULL)
>     {   
>       printf("Usage Message: File is not open temp/test.txt");
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
>      fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
>       fclose(fp);
>     }
>  }
> ```

- Also remember that when you dealing with file operation always you have to check your file is opened/create or not using Usage message. Actually it is good sign of programming.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I found the code work with the following on my PC...

instead of **"/tmp/test.txt"**, make it **"tmp/test.txt"**.
Yes, just remove the **"/"**.